# saved state of check box in list view after checked xamarin.andriod (edit with solution )

Tags: c#, android, listview, checkbox, xamarin.android

i have DialogFragment contians listview have check box and text view  i want saved state of checkBox after checked i do  that saved the states in `ISharedPreferences`  but it not worked 
What is problem ??

this is my listViewNames Adapter

`

```
public class ViewHoldername : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public EditText etdName { get; set; }
        public EditText etdTitle { get; set; }


    }
class listViewNames : BaseAdapter<logINsnc.Customers_transfer>
{

     private ISharedPreferences savePreferences;
     static     private ISharedPreferencesEditor savePrefsEditor;
     private Boolean saveLogin;  
     public static  CheckBox namechecbox ;
     public static List<string> listNameChecked = new List<string>();
     Activity activity;

     List<logINsnc.Customers_transfer> ArriveList = new List<logINsnc.Customers_transfer>();

   // SQliteDB bb = new SQliteDB();
    logINsnc bb = new logINsnc();

    async public Task<List<logINsnc.Customers_transfer>> Add_DataList(string s)
    {

      //  string Get =  ExpandableListAdapter.Globals.voucher;
        ArriveList = await bb.DetailsNamelistForPOpUp(s);
        return ArriveList;

    }
    public string GetVoucher()
    {
        string voucher = "";
        return voucher;
    }
    public listViewNames()
    {

    }

    public listViewNames(Activity activity, List<logINsnc.Customers_transfer> Arrive)
        : base()
    {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.ArriveList = Arrive;
    }


    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return ArriveList.Count();
        }
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    public override long  GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return ArriveList[position].SrvOrd_Sub_Id;
    }


    public override logINsnc.Customers_transfer this[int position]
    {
        get { return ArriveList[position]; }
    }




    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
          savePreferences = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("savePrefs", FileCreationMode.Private);
        Globals.custimersCount = Count;

     activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Details_Template, null);
        var item = ArriveList[position];
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Custmize_Name_layout, null);

        Globals.Ser_Sub = item.SrvOrd_Sub_Id;


         view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.etdNamelis).Text = item.Name.ToString();
         view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.etdTitle).Text = item.Title;
         namechecbox = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBoxnam);
      //   checkBoxButton = (CheckBox)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBoxButton);
         namechecbox.Tag = item.Title + ";"+ position+";"+item.Name;


         savePrefsEditor = savePreferences.Edit();

         saveLogin = savePreferences.GetBoolean("saveLogind" + position + item.Name, false);
         if (saveLogin == true)
         { 
              namechecbox.Checked = true;

         }  

        namechecbox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        namechecbox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckedChangeListener(this.activity)); 

         return view;

    }


    private class CheckedChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
    {
        private Activity activity;

        public CheckedChangeListener(Activity activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
        {

            String[] tag = buttonView.Tag.ToString().Split(';');
            string name = tag[0];
               if (isChecked && !savePreferences.Contains("saveLogind" + tag[1] + tag[2]  ))

            {

            savePrefsEditor.PutBoolean("saveLogind" + tag[1]+tag[2], true);

            savePrefsEditor.Commit();  

                listNameChecked.Add(name);
                Globals.listName = listNameChecked;

            }
            else
            {

                listNameChecked.Remove(name);

               editor.Remove("saveLogind" + tag[1] + tag[2] );
               savePrefsEditor.Commit(); 
                Globals.listName = listNameChecked;


            }
        }
    }



    public static class Globals
    {
        public static int  Ser_Sub { get; set; }  
        public static List<string> listName;
         public static int custimersCount { get; set; }  
        // public static int TransName { get; set; }
        public static string nameChecked { get; set; }
    }



}
```

`

Comment: Did you remember to parse the preferences when displaying the checkbox? It won't happen by itself.

Comment: sorry i am  new in xamarin.andriod    please more explain ?    do you mean namechecbox.Checked = true; in if function ??

Comment: Nevermind, sorry I found it in your code
(Quick note, comparing bool to true is pointless, you can just put 
if(saveLogin){
    ...
}

Comment: i try this ,,  But same error ,,  don't work

Comment: Try viewing every entry in preferences to make sure the one you are looking for is there.

Comment: please explain your comment  ??

Comment: Your preferences file is a list of key-value pairs. Maybe you get false all the time, because your list doesn't contain the key you are looking up. If you debug and look into the preferences maybe it will shed some light on why you get the wrong value.

Comment: thanks for reply i will try debug i will see ...